# how to set visibility for css class with jquery and animate function

Tags: jquery, css

i want set visibility for *right* css class with jquery and animate function, so use this code:

```
$(".right").animate({ "visibility": "hidden" }, "slow");
```

and

```
$(".right").animate({ visibility: hidden});
```

but this not working.

Comment: use `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`

Comment: I want animate (visibility) for left to right. not fadeOut

Comment: @kakamishoo how do you expect to animate visibility? it only has two states - either visible or hidden. There is no inbetween... Perhaps you're using the wrong term? did you mean opacity, or width/height?

Comment: For animate for left to right, you can have a look on this example - http://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/KFmLv/

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any **numeric** CSS property
>
> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
> except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
> animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used)

You can not animate `visibility` since it is not a **numeric** CSS property.